# Slightly custom SBL to use single quotes instead of double quotes

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am starting to learn latex, and I really have no idea how easy or hard this is going to be, I need to focus on my assignment that is almost due rather than learning latex :D My institution uses *almost* SBL, that is I can use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}

Stuff\autocite[1]{book}

\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

But I need it to output single quotes in the bibliography/footnotes instead of double quotes. Is this something that can be easily achieved, or am I going to have to learn how to make my own template?

Comment: Are you (as recommended) using `csquotes` with `biblatex`? If so, then it is largely a matter of setting the right options? (A MWE would make it easier for others to help you....)

Comment: I have no idea what csquotes or MWE is. I just want to change how the quotes appear in the bibliography, and in the footnotes, where the footnote is generated by autocite

Comment: MWE: [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). `csquotes` is a package (so is `biblatex`); you should use them together.

Comment: If I knew how to make a minimum working example, then I wouldn't have a question to ask—That is to say, my document isn't broken, I need to know what to add to it to change the quote format output when using bib latex

Comment: It is a term of art, but it doesn't mean that it must 'work'. If you read the link(s) more carefully, you'll see it is about providing a minimal file that includes only what is needed to reproduce the problem/issue. (And, if we must be pedantic about everything, it sounds like your file does in fact 'work', it just produces output you'd like to change. So provide an MWE that produces the output you'd like to change.)

Comment: Ok I added the other stuff that is in a normal file. I still don't know how to change the quotes that go into the bibliography

Comment: Yeah, ways to change this will be posted as answers. But it is very helpful that the answers all start from your starting assumptions (which are best revealed through the MWE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all primary-level quotation marks should be 'single' rather than "double" (British, rather than American), you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}% recommended for use with csquotes & biblatex
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{file.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

This is how the \enquote{Brits} use quotation marks.

Stuff\autocite[1]{bertram}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Edit** Sounds like (as often happens) someone with no experience in typography is setting the typographical rules. If you need "American" quotation marks in the text and 'British' quotation marks in your citations and bibliography, you have to work a little harder.

But this requirement is ambiguous because 'British' punctuation is more 'logical'. That is, it falls inside punctuation marks when it the punctuation is not a part of the original quotation. ("American" punctuation seems to be based on aesthetics: if it looks "nicer," then you stick the puncutation on the "inside"; but if it does not, then you don't.) It is possible to do either.

**Type One:** British quotation marks with logical punctuation for citations and references:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,2.25in},height=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[british,american]{babel}%
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}%
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{file.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\selectlanguage{british}}
\AtEveryCite{\selectlanguage{british}}

\begin{document}

This is not how the \enquote{Brits} use quotation marks; but it is how
they do references and citations\ldots

Stuff\autocite[1]{bertram}

\selectlanguage{british}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: example-2]

**Type Two:** British quotation marks, but with American-style punctuation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british,american]{babel}%
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}%
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{file.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{\selectlanguage{british}\uspunctuation}
\AtEveryCite{\selectlanguage{british}\uspunctuation}

\begin{document}

This is not how the \enquote{Brits} use quotation marks or puncutation.

Stuff\autocite[1]{bertram}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: example-3]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this partially solves it—in as much, that that it allows a minimal viable solution. The only catch is, as I indicated _"But I need it to output single quotes in the bibliography/footnotes instead of double quotes."_ I don't really want to change the quotes for the whole document. However I can go ahead and use literal quotes in the main body to avoid them being altered. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob -- I updated the answer with different variants. Hopefully one of them addresses the weird style rules you need to follow.

Comment: Thanks @jon Just to be clear, I really appreciate your help. I completely accept your suggestion that what I suggested may be typographically illogical. The motivation for my question is driven by the rules provided to me by my institution. This is pure speculation, but perhaps, when it comes to Australia, the combined influence of the U.K. and U.S. confuses things somewhat. :)

Comment: @Jacob -- Yes, not to worry: I didn't mean to suggest it was you. Often institutions devise weird rules that we must obey. In such cases, complaining here is one of the few places where we're likely to get a receptive audience!